# A Reference in Klein's Book

Tags: reference-request

F. Klein mentions a certain Blumenthal in his famous book on the history of mathematics in 19th century with the following verse(when he was talking about the curvature in space):

> Die Menschen fassen kaum es
>
> Das Krümmungsmaß des Raumes

**Question:** I am wondering whom this Blumenthal Klein referred to. Is he Otto Blumenthal or somebody else?

Comment: google books alleges that some article in Nova Acta Leopoldina in 1987 says it was Otto Blumenthal, but it is paywalled away from me.

Comment: Thank you. I do find a paper of Howard Stein, attributing the verse to Otto Blumenthal, but I wonder what is his information source....

Comment: http://strangebeautiful.com/other-texts/helmholtz-origin-signif-geom-axioms-stein.pdf

Comment: Butzer and Volkmann's 2006 paper about  Blumenthal cites 3 obits.  The one by Sommerfeld looks like it might have this detail,  (A. Sommerfeld, F. Krauss, Otto Blumenthal zum Gedächtnis, Jahrbuch der RWTH Aachen 4 (1951) 21–25)  but it's in a journal that does not seem to be on-line.

Comment: Klein died in 1925. Zentralblatt mentions only one mathematician with the name Blumenthal, whose earliest work predates 1925: this is Otto. However the list of Otto's books in Zbl does not contain a book on history of mathematics. One possibility is that this book was not reviewed (which is very unikely). Can you determine approximate date when Klein referred on it?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko I think you misread the OP's slightly awkwardly phrased question.  The famous book is Klein's _Verlesungen_ of 1926, which, on page 153 (I think)  quotes Blumenthal's verse "Die Menschen..."  Blumenthal is not claimed to have written a history of mathematics.